# Is it possible to write the backend using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backend

As we all know, JavaScript is widespread on the web. For client side scripting it does a great job.

But is it possible to take JavaScript outside the browser? For example, writing a streaming socket or writing DB, doing schedule job? Things like that in the backend? Thanks.

Comment: It's already seven years since this post, and I can't believe that there was a time where JS as backend or server-side was hard to believe.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can do a lot of backend things in Javascript.

There is a lot of frameworks and application that runs Javascript as a backend, all with different pros and cons.

### [NodeJs](http://nodejs.org/)

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

### [OPA](http://opalang.org/)

> Opa is an advanced application framework for JavaScript. All aspects are directly written in Opa: Frontend code, backend code, database queries and configuration. And everything is strongly statically typed.

### [CommonJs](http://www.commonjs.org/)

> The CommonJS API will fill that gap by defining APIs that handle many common application needs, ultimately providing a standard library as rich as those of Python, Ruby and Java. The intention is that an application developer will be able to write an application using the CommonJS APIs and then run that application across different JavaScript interpreters and host environments.

### [Vertx.io](http://vertx.io/)

> Vert.x is the framework for the next generation of asynchronous, effortlessly scalable, concurrent applications.
>   Vert.x is an event driven application framework that runs on the JVM - a run-time with real concurrency and unrivalled performance. Vert.x then exposes the API in Ruby, Java, Groovy, JavaScript and Python. So you choose what language you want to use. Scala and Clojure support is on the roadmap too.

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). It does a certain number of things very well, but may not be best suited for all purposes.

If you are looking to do stuff that involves a lot of parallell processes and/or you want to keep persistent connections open to and from a user's browser, then it may be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Along with node.js, have a look at [vert.x](http://vertx.io/).

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://icalc.cn) is written by node.js

Using [websvr](https://github.com/newghost/websvr), it's Java style have filter and handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it , but for server-side JS the most populate framework is nodejs http://nodejs.org

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can utilize JavaScript outside the browser.  Both for server-side scripting (similar to JSP or ASP).  This can most notably be accomplished using Node.js (http://www.commonjs.org/) however there are other options available.  Similarly you can create aps entirely outside of the webspace using the CommonJS API (http://www.commonjs.org/).

Check out the Wikipedia article about JavaScript (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Server-side_JavaScript).