# Java script and full-stack JavaScript difference?

Tags: javascript

What is difference between JavaScript and full-stack JavaScript.

Both are same or not.

Comment: That's quite a nonsense

Answer (score 1):

Full stack - in simplification - generally means Front-end and Back-end. You can do backend with NodeJS, and do frontend with frameworks like React or Angular. All with Javascript.

Comment: Full-Stack is much more than just front- and backend development

Comment: @LucaKiebel you are right, but I didn't want to go into more details.

Answer (score 1):

First off, JavaScript is a programming language, no matter if it's used in the browser, on the server or compiled into apps and desktop programs.

Generally, as @Tomasz wrote, with full-stack people refer to developers that can develop on all (or at least multiple) platforms, but it's still the same language. The difference lies in the usage of certain special bits of (third-party-)code.

Node has `packages` and many platforms (like electron) use those to accomplish their usage of the language. 
On the frontend you'll likely find `frameworks` that make it easier to interact with what the user sees.

So to answer your question, yes, both are the same *language*, but they are not *the same thing*.

Answer (score 0):

Full stack: Backend(Server Side) + Front-end(Client Side)

Backend Technology: NodeJs ([Role of Backend Technologies](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/back-end-web-developer/))
Front-end Technology: React Js, Angular Js etc. ([more](https://github.com/showcases/front-end-javascript-frameworks))

For More Detail read the following URL:

- [Is it possible to write the backend using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652026/is-it-possible-to-write-the-backend-using-javascript)
- https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript/javascript-frameworks-love
- http://thefullstack.xyz/full-stack-javascript-developer/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/introduction-to-full-stack-javascript/